# role of get_unit_value in boost ODEINT

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, odeint

In the following code from [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/numeric/odeint/util/unit_helper.hpp):

```
template<class T , class Enabler = void >
struct get_unit_value_impl
{
    static T value(const T &t)
    {
        return t;
    }
    typedef T result_type;
};
```

...

```
template<class T>
typename detail::get_unit_value_impl<T>::result_type get_unit_value(const T &t)
{
    return detail::get_unit_value_impl<T>::value(t);
}
```

The role of `get_unit_value` is unclear to me. What does it do? we pass something to it and it returns the same value. Why should someone wrap it into a structure? Does it do anything except for slowing down the run time?

This code is called from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/default_operations.hpp):

```
template< class Fac1 = double >
struct rel_error
{
    const Fac1 m_eps_abs , m_eps_rel , m_a_x , m_a_dxdt;

    rel_error( Fac1 eps_abs , Fac1 eps_rel , Fac1 a_x , Fac1 a_dxdt )
    : m_eps_abs( eps_abs ) , m_eps_rel( eps_rel ) , m_a_x( a_x ) , m_a_dxdt( a_dxdt ) { }


    template< class T1 , class T2 , class T3 >
    void operator()( T3 &t3 , const T1 &t1 , const T2 &t2 ) const
    {
        using std::abs;
        set_unit_value( t3 , abs( get_unit_value( t3 ) ) / ( m_eps_abs + m_eps_rel * ( m_a_x * abs( get_unit_value( t1 ) ) + m_a_dxdt * abs( get_unit_value( t2 ) ) ) ) );
    }

    typedef void result_type;
};
```

Comment: The runtime should not be affected by this template. The optimizer should eliminate it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to copy one of the specializations:

```
template<class T , class Enabler = void >
struct get_unit_value_impl
{
    static T value(const T &t)
    {
        return t;
    }
    typedef T result_type;
};

#ifndef __CUDACC__
template<class Unit , class T>
struct get_unit_value_impl< boost::units::quantity< Unit , T> >
{
    static T value( const boost::units::quantity< Unit , T> &t )
    {
        return t.value();
    }
    typedef T result_type;
};
#endif
```

The point `get_unit_value()` is to take in either a value and return it, or a `boost::unit::quantity<Unit, T>` and return the value off of it. That way, the caller doesn't need to worry about if `t` is just an `int` or something more complicated:

```
int x = 7;
quantity<length> L = 2.0*meters;

get_unit_value(x); // 7
get_unit_value(L); // 2.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I understand the purpose better. Still it is not fully clear. What I perceived from the that is if there is no CUDA ACCelerator, then take `value` of the argument? But if there is CUDA ACC dont do that? but why?

Comment: @torbani That I cannot say. I don't know anything about CUDA and why that function is unimplemented in that case. I can just say why it exists in general.

Comment: @torbani The CUDA compiler is notorious for breaking at the sight of any Boost header; I guess somebody tried to be defensive on Boost's side.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with Cuda. Can you explained it in more detail if there is a problem. Barry is right, we only introduced it, to ensure compatibility with Boost.Units.